# PHP Performance optimization

Tags: php, optimization, project

I'm trying to optimise PHP code to manage code easily and to speedup page execution time. My strategy is to create a file **core_functions.php** and defined all functions in this file. Then include this file into every other file of the project.

I need to know is it best practice to have all function defined in one file or it is best practice to split the function into different files and include where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is actually going to hurt performance. In each page that loads the 6000 line file the PHP interpreter has to interpret that whole file. You'd be better of splitting your functions into modules and have each page only reference the modules it needs.

This reinterpretation of PHP files on each page load can be reduced though by using a caching mechanism that caches the compiled byte code of interpreted files.

There is a list of frameworks that do this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators

Comment: Ok Thanks. what about if the core_function have the functions calling at other files. does it also affect. Like function read(){include 'read.php';} function write(){include 'write.php';}

Comment: If you have one file that includes other files then when you include that file it will also have to interpret all of the other included files and so on recursively.